# ASP.NET MVC Identity Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 4 and i'm developing an application. In my application i have a districts table with properties id, name. i want to associate this district table to applicationUser in the identityModel.cs file. My main goal is to establish a one to many relationship between my users and districts.
As in, a more than one user maps to a single district. i tried this in my applicationUser class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("District")]
    public int DistrictID { get; set; }
    public virtual District District { get; set; }
}
```

this is my districts table too

```
public class District
{
    public int DistrictID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="District Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    //Retrieving the region value through the id
    [Display(Name = "Region")]
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

    public virtual List<AreaCouncil> AreaCouncils { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

When i try to scaffold, i receive the following error message:

> 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Basis.Models.Region'. One or more validation >errors were detected during model generation.
>   Basis.Models.IdentityUserLogin::Entity Type 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key >defined. Define the key for this Entity Type.
>   Basis.Models.IdentityUserRole::Entity Type 'IdentityUserRole' has no key >defined. Define the key for this Entity Type.'........

Can anyone please help me out in accomplishing this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

In ApplicationUser you just want a property of District. You don't want to have it virtual unless you actually want runtime polymorphism.

I would name the property something else than District. E.g.

```
public District HomeDistrict {get;set}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IdentityUser` already has a PK. remove

```
public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
```

from your `ApplicationUser` Class